# Time fixed effect dropped in regression with unit-invariant variable

Tags: econometrics, multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model

I am estimating a model with country and time fixed effects (years). Among the regressors I have a country-invariant variable (dollar oil price) which is of interest. I have noticed that some year fixed effects are omitted due to collinearity (equal to the number of oil price regressors: if I put oil and lag of oil, two last years would be omitted).

1. Is it problematic that not all year fixed effects are included?
2. How year fixed effect (which capture all sort of shocks) can be perfectly collinear with oil price?